# Can a player represent more than one team?

Tags: cricket, tournaments

In Champions Leage T20 2013, Kumar Sangakkara chose to play for Kandurata Maroons team, although he is the captain for Sunrisers Hyderabad. Now Kandurata Maroons is out of CLT20. Can  Sangakkara now join Sunrisers Hyderabad?? Is there any rule in cricket that permits a player to get switched over or even represent for another team as in case of Sangakkara??

Comment: Interesting question. The CLT20 is a mess because of issues like this, the best player such as Sangakkara and Chris Gayle play in so many T20 leagues that issues like this will keep coming up.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is NO. The players were asked to select the team before the start of CLT20 and Sangakkara chose Maroons team. So he will not be able to reverse his decision in the middle of the tournament.

Also from the cricinfo news:

> The Champions League rules also state that if a cricketer is a part of
>   two qualifying teams, and does not play for the team from his home
>   country in the tournament, the team he represents must pay his home
>   side $150,000.

Source: Various News and [check this cricinfo news link](http://www.espncricinfo.com/champions-league-twenty20-2013/content/story/665813.html)

Answer (score 0):

I emailed to www.lords.org regarding this question since I couldn't find any law regarding this. The reply I got from them is:

> Thank you for your email. The question of whether a player can switch teams during a tournament depends upon the rules of that particular tournament as decided by its governing body and, as such, does not fall under the remit of the Laws of cricket.

That means there is no law in Laws of cricket. It totally up to the particular tournament's rules.